# Load all html dependent files: js, css in the same way like browser does

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have SPA application.

Main goal is to test performance of application with https://artillery.io.

Since application is SPA, I would like to mimic scenario where all static content are loaded when user first time open application in browser. Actually during first request within `artillery` scenarios, I expect that all resources like, `html`, `js` and `css` files will be loaded.

One way is to hardcode all `GET` calls which are performed when resources are loaded, but since `js` files support versioning I would need to change files names as soon as new version will be released.

Is there any way behaves within test scenarios like a browser? For instance when html page is loaded all dependencies are loaded as well?

Comment: This is something like you want http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You can try [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)

JS code:

```
var timeoutMs = 25000;
var result = {};

var timerId = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('pageError: timeout');
    page.close();
    phantom.exit();
}, timeoutMs);

var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address, output, size;

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 TEST';
page.viewportSize = { width: 1280, height: 1024 };

page.customHeaders = {
    'Connection'     : 'keep-alive',
    'Accept'         : 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'identity',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3'
};

address = system.args[1];

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
    result.loadMS = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
};

var startTime = new Date().getTime();
page.open(address, function (status) {    
    result.status = status;
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    console.log('<<<<RESULT>>>>');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    setTimeout(function(){
        phantom.exit();
    }, 0);
});
```

Then call it:

```
phantomjs load.js https://artillery.io
```

Result:

> {"loadMS":2216,"status":"success"}